# Generalized partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\kappa>0$ be a cardinal and $X$ be a set. We set $[X]^\kappa = \{A \in {\cal P}(X): |A| = \kappa\}$.

If ${\cal A}\subseteq {\cal P}(X)$ we say that ${\cal B} \subseteq {\cal P}(X)$ is an ${\cal A}$-*partition* if for every $X \in {\cal A}$ there is a *unique* $Y\in {\cal B}$ with $X\subseteq Y$. Note that ${\cal A}$-partitions may not exist, for instance if ${\cal A}$ has 2 distinct members such that one is a subset of the other. Trivially, if ${\cal A} = \{\{x\}: x\in X\}$ then an ${\cal A}$-partition is just a partition in the conventional sense.

If $a \in b \in \omega$ with $a > 1$, is there ${\cal B}\subseteq [\omega]^b$ such that ${\cal B}$ is an $[\omega]^a$-partition?

Comment: Can you just construct $\mathcal{B}$ greedily by at every step, chosing the minimal $a$ element subset $S$ that is not already a subset of an element in $\mathcal{B}$ and adding $S \cup T$ to $\mathcal{B}$ where $T$ is a set of cardinality $b-a$ containing only large numbers that are not in any subset already in $\mathcal{B}$?